# Haskell metaprogramming at runtime

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming

What is the easiest way to generate code as a string/AST/some other representation during runtime, and then run the code and compute properties of the resulting values during the same program execution?

The three ways I could think of would be some sort of “eval” function that takes a string or an equivalent expression representing a program and runs it and returns the output, a “reload module” function which dynamically reloads a file during runtime (in which case one could write the generated code to file and then reload), or writing the generated code to a file while including a line in that file which serializes the generated values, running that file, and then reloading those values from the serialization.

Unfortunately, I haven’t had any look finding a solution with any of these methods yet - dynamic reloading doesn’t appear to be supported, and serialization apparently doesn’t work on functions.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint)

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate and I guess I'm enough to close it.  Feel free to rebuke that with specific request and how the other question is different and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't see how to load entire modules using hint - is this possible?

Comment: Well you can  `setImports ["Data.Map"]` for installed modules.  Are you wanting to interpret multiple non-installed modules and some consumer of those modules? That is a different problem that I don't immediately know the answer to.